# Improving for() loops with other options

Tags: c, cs50

I have the following code:

```
void record_preferences(int ranks[]){                               // Update preferences given one voter's ranks

    for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++){                       //Cycle through candidates
        for(int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++){                   //Cycle through rank list
            if((i == ranks[j]) && (j != candidate_count - 1)){      //If found and not last candidate
                for(int k = j + 1; k < candidate_count; k++){
                    preferences[i][ranks[k]]++;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

When I look at this custom function I made, I felt like there is too many `for() loop`.

**Question:** Is there a way to make this code more efficient or possibly can I use recursion with it.

I tried formulating on how to use recursion, but I am getting stuck and can't seem to find a way.

Variables that can't be changed (but you can make more variables if you need to):

- `candidate_count` is a global variable and equal to 9
- `preferences[i][j]` is a global variable. # of voters who prefer Candidate i over Candidate j
- `ranks[]` is a local variable. This var stores user's input of their candidate ranking

[Link to entire code](https://hastebin.com/raniwivejo.cpp) Voting method is [Tideman Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranked_pairs)

Comment: The code is correct but I would like to know other option unless there is a website that improves code quality.

Comment: The second half of the `if` is not needed; the innermost loop will terminate if `j == candidate_count - 1` without looping at all.  OTOH, it doesn't do much harm either.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I just noticed that. But is there any way to improve the code? or should I leave it as is.

Comment: I'd make multiple cosmetic changes, but I don't immediately see any substantive changes.  However, I also don't fully understand what the code is doing, though it might be tabulating (computing) results for some sort of rank-choice voting system.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler https://hastebin.com/raniwivejo.cpp entire code if you need a better understanding of what is happening. Also, it using tideman method of voting.

Comment: Question is more suitable for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @kaylum Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++){                       //Cycle through candidates
    for(int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++){                   //Cycle through rank list
        if((i == ranks[j]) && (j != candidate_count - 1)){      //If found and not last candidate
```

1. We are only doing any work in the cases where `i == ranks[j]`, so looping over `i` values is not useful. Instead, we can directly verify that `ranks[j]` is a valid value, and use it.
2. Since we want to skip the case where `j == candidate_count - 1`, it's simpler to just adjust the loop bounds.

So:

```
for(int j = 0; j < candidate_count - 1; j++) { // Cycle through ranks, except the last
    int i = ranks[j]; // consider the one possible candidate
    if (i >= 0 && i < candidate_count) { // if the value is valid
```

Rename the variables as you see fit, of course :)